# MUI X Data Grid table pagination not responding to theme

Tags: css, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

In dark mode the MUI X Data Grid pagination text stays black, it's color is (0,0,0, 0.87). I can't find a reference to anywhere in my code base that it connects back to in rgba() or hex form.

```
export default createTheme({
  ...<other mui theme stuff>
  components: {
    ...<skip>
    MuiDataGrid: { ...dataGrid },
    ...<skip over a bunch of other components>
    MuiTablePagination: { ...tablePagination },
  },
});
```

but the MuiTablePagination does not seem to apply to the data grid's table pagination no matter what I replace the `...tablePagination` with
[image: web console]

can't think of a way to target it without messing up the theme switching. any help would be great thanks!